# Can an aspx project create a file and email it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email-attachments

I am developing an *.aspx.cs project which generates text data.  I need to save this away for the user to use later.  I've tried saving it on the client machine with:

```
FileStream fStream = new FileStream("C:\\MyDir\\Data.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```

But this fails with an 'unauthorised access' message.  Is it at all possible to create local files?
If not, I'd be happy sending it as an email attachment (not in the email body)

I would have thought this would be a common requirement, but I can't find anything useful with a websearch.

I'd be grateful for any help.

Tony Reynolds (UK)

Comment: You can create files on the server and let the user download them, but you can't create files directly on a users machine afaik.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes things clearer.  Is it possible somehow to create a 'file' in memory and use that as an email attachment?

Comment: You could also allow the user to download the file from the server, probably easier for the user than emailing it.

Comment: You are correct that you can create a representation of a file in memory, and then email that. Look at the available methods and their overloads on the library you're using to send email.

Answer (score 2):

First of all this command

```
FileStream("C:\\MyDir\\Data.txt" ....
```

is running on server side, and apparently you do not have permissions to write there. Try to save it on some other directory on server that you have permissions, and connect it with your user actions, and then use it.

---

> I've tried saving it on the client machine

You do not have and will never have permissions to write on client machine - this is not have to do with asp.net, but with the browsers. Also remember you are not run asp.net on client. Asp.net sites is not a windows program that runs on client, its runs on server on IIS.

Comment: Thanks everybody.  That makes it much clearer.